# How to calculate the set bit positions in a number?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit

If n = 100011 in binary, then I want to retrieve the positions of set bits which in this case are 1,5,6 when measured from left to right.

How to calculate such positions without literally checking for bit is zero or not by going to every bit position?

Comment: Binary numbers, like ordinary decimal numbers, are usually written right-to-left. I.e. the most significant bit is to the left, and the least significant bit is to the right. And usually the bit-numbers are zero-based (i.e. the least significant bit, the rightmost bit, the "first" bit, is bit number zero).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the most common convention, a binary number is written in the order as a number in other common positional representations (decimal etc): with the least significant digit in the rightmost position. It also makes more sense to label that digit as "digit zero", so that the label of every digit corresponds with the exponent in the associated weight (eg bit 0 has weight 2<sup>0</sup>=1 and so forth). This doesn't really matter, it's easy enough to re-number the digits, but it's usually easier to follow the conventions.

Since you asked

> How to calculate such positions without literally checking for bit is zero or not by going to every bit position?

I will address that portion of the question. Checking the bits one by one is not completely disastrous however. Even for BigInts. The number of results could be as high as the number of bits anyway. For numbers known to be *sparse*, there is still not much that can be done - every bit has to be checked *somehow* because if any bit is ignored completely, that bit might have been set and we'd miss it. But in the context of a machine word, there are tricks, for example based on find-first-set.

Using the [find-first-set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set) function (or count trailing zeroes), the index of the set bit with the lowest index can be found in one step (if you accept this function as being one step, which is a reasonable assumption on most hardware, and in theory you can just define it to be one step), and then that bit can be removed so the next find-first-set will find the index of the *next* bit. For example:

```
while bitmask != 0:
    yield return find-first-set(bitmask)
    bitmask &= bitmask - 1 // remove lowest set bit
```

This is easy to adapt to BigInts, just do this on every limb of the number and add the appropriate offset.

Answer (score 1):

To do that you use masks.

Each position from right to left is a power of two.
For example `0101` is `1*2ˆ0 + 0*2ˆ1 + 1*2ˆ2 + 0*1ˆ3 = 1+0+4+0 = 5`

Then to check if these two bits are on against a `bytesToTest` variable you `AND` with 5: `byteToTest & 5 == 5`

Given that `1 & 0 = 0` and `1 & 1 = 1`

If bytesToTest is 1111 then 1111 & 0101 will give 0101
If bytesToTest is 1010 then 1010 & 0101 will give 0000

Following this reasoning for the particular case of 100011
To retrieve 1, 5, and 6 from left to right (the three ones set to 1)

The mask is: `1+2+32 = 35`

With this information you should be able to define individual masks for each bit, test one by one, and be able to answer in which position you find bits that are on and in which bits that are off.

Comment: could you please relate your response with the example number n given in question?

Comment: Also, it's not necessary that the number has to be represented in binary only. Could be in decimal and we are free to use any bitwise operations to get the set bit positions in the number.

Comment: But that does not make sense. If I have a number of n bits, how would I know the bit masks for the positions I am trying to identify. The bits that are set could be in any location. If I check for every position then, that's equivalent of checking individual bits.

Comment: n is allways a known number because it is bound to a primitive data type. See the las part of my answer. By defining individual masks for each bit you can test one by one. The one most on the right will test agains 1, the next one against 2, the next, 4, and so forth.

Comment: @user3243499 it's exceedingly unlikely that you are working with decimal numbers on a computer. Not impossible, but you'd have to be doing it on purpose.